# Cardinality Violation during Views contextual filter setup, how to fix this?

Tags: 7, views

I'm currently getting this error in my views setup:

**SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column**

I'm not sure why its giving this error as it seems like it should work. I have a contextual filter that matches taxonomy term id's. I have it configured to pass in an array() of tid's, but it throws the error if its more than one. What could be wrong?

Below are screenshots of my setup and sql statement generated by views:

http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/8079/f4bw.jpg

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reading the instructions for multiple views contextual filter arguments you get the solution:

> **Allow multiple values**:
>   If selected, users can enter multiple values in
>   the form of 1+2+3 (for OR) or 1,2,3 (for AND).

So if you need an **OR operator** you should return a **string** of "1+2+3" and if you need an **AND operator** you should **return** a string of "1,2,3".

So don't return an array() but a string.